# How to avoid building an entire HTML page in the server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

If you look at code below on the client.on method, I res.write the entire output file because I did not know how to get the message to display with the html file. Is there a similar way of doing this rather than res.writing anything? Res.write is also very slow while when I used res.send it was very fast. Is there any other way I can do this? I am fairly new to node js

```
//Sending UDP message to TFTP server
//dgram modeule to create UDP socket
var express= require('express'), fs= require('fs'),path = require('path'),util = require('util'),dgram= require('dgram'),client= dgram.createSocket('udp4'),bodyParser = require('body-parser'),app = express()
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static('public'));

//Reading in the html file for input page
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var html = fs.readFileSync('index2.html');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
});

//reading in html file for output page
app.get('/output', function(req, res){
    var html = fs.readFileSync('index3.html');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
});

//Recieving UDP message 
app.post('/output', function(req, res){
//Define the host and port values of UDP
var HOST= '192.168.0.136';
var PORT= 69;
//Reading in the user's command, converting to hex
var message = new Buffer(req.body.number, 'hex');

//Sends packets to TFTP
client.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, HOST, function (err, bytes) {
        if (err) throw err;
  });

//Recieving message back and printing it out to webpage
client.on('message', function (message) {
  res.write('<html>');
  res.write('<head>');
  res.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">');
  res.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />');
  res.write('</head>');
  res.write('</body>');
  res.write('<img src="logo.png" alt="rolls royce logo">');
  res.write('<ul>');
  res.write('<li><a href="/">Input</a></li>');
  res.write('<li><a class="active" href="/output">Output</a></li>');
  res.write(' </ul>');
  res.write('</br></br>')
  res.write('<div>');
  res.write(' <h4>Output is:</h4>');
  res.write(message.toString());
  res.write('</div>');
  res.write('</body>');
  res.write('</html>');
  });
});


//Setting up listening server
app.listen(3000, "192.168.0.136");
console.log('Listening at 192.168.0.136:3000');
```

Comment: `"too many var statements"`!!! :P

Comment: And, don't code an entire HTML page into your Javascript.  Use file-based resources to hold HTML pages or HTML templates.  Or, even better, use one of the template systems built for node.js and express where all the heavy work has already been done for you.

Comment: @SpYk3HH I deleted the ones I did not need, but I need the rest. Is that still alot? is there something wrong if too many var statementS?

Comment: lol, it's a very old programmers joke in relation to not using `,` seperator, although it evolved to be a joke with a JSLint issue. Basically, it's an old argument between doing like you have, or doing it like: `var express= require('express'), 
 fs= require('fs'), 
 util = require('util')` Ipersonally prefer the latter. Seeing all those `var`'s is generally a dead give away of "new guy". As to your issue, I'm not entirely familiar with the problem as I haven't used node much yet, but will be in the future, so i'm bookmarking this for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an HTML template, save it into a part of the file system which is accessible from the server, then return it to the HTTP client *feeded* with the right value.

You could write your own template engine (and use regular expressions to make the correct substitutions), or you could you use [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) for instance.

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
    fs.readFile('/etc/templates/message.jade', function(_, template) {
        let body = jade.compile(template)({
                       message: message.toString()
                   });

        return res.end(body);
    });
});
```

Where message.jade might be

```
doctype html
html
    body
        h4 Output is: #{message}
```

Comment: @patidar, if I understand you question, code that I wrote in the answer should be enough. jade.compile() when passed a jade template will return you a function that when is passed an object will use it to produce a valid HTML string. Thus, `jade.compile(template){message: message.toString()}`